Create margin notes in the header and footer area
For a historically accurate liturgical Gospel book, I am trying to create top and bottom margin notes that appear within the header and footer that display rubrical information for the given section of the gospel. It will serve as customized headers and footers. There will not be any other header and footer information displayed on the pages outside of the notes I put in. I need them to be centered within the body text area. It seems to make the most sense to treat these notes as margin notes rather than unique headers and footers for every page, but I dont care, as long as I can easily attach the notes to any given point in the text like a normal margin note. Many attempts so far with various suggestions from ChatGPT have produced more problems than solutions. I included the \topmarginnote commands in the body text, which is what I would like the command to use. Here is my preamble and the beginning of the text:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openany,dvipsnames]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{marginnote} % For margin notes

\hyphenpenalty=5000
\tolerance=2000

% Set up geometry
\geometry{
  inner=25mm,
  outer=35mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  marginparwidth=30mm,
  marginparsep=10mm,
}

% Set the main font to KJV1611
\setmainfont[HyphenChar=8208, Style=Historic,Kerning=On,Scale=1.5]{KJV1611.otf}

% Set up headers and footers with scrlayer-scrpage
\clearpairofpagestyles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{} % Clear other header contents

% Set KOMA-Script options to remove header and footer lines
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=0pt, footsepline=0pt}

% Remove page numbers
\cfoot{}

% Remove indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Define shortcut for BrickRed color
\newcommand{\brickred}[1]{\textcolor{BrickRed}{#1}}

% Define margin note command for liturgical readings
\newcommand{\readingnote}[2][0pt]{%
  \marginnote{\makebox[0pt][c]{\brickred{\textbf{#2}}}}[#1]
}

% Define top and bottom margin notes using low-level TeX commands
\newcommand{\topmarginnote}[1]{%
  \smash{\hbox to \textwidth{\vbox to 0pt{\vskip-2.5cm\hbox{\hfil\brickred{#1}\hfil}\vss}}}%
}

\newcommand{\bottommarginnote}[1]{%
  \smash{\hbox to \textwidth{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\vskip-\footskip\hbox{\hfil\brickred{#1}\hfil}}}}%
}

% Define chapter heading style using KOMA-Script options
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Huge\KJV\color{BrickRed}}
\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{}
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{}{}{%
    \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\centering#3}%
  }%
}

% Set font family for titles
\newfontfamily\KJV{KJV1611.otf}

% Define title page style
\newcommand{\titlepagedecor}{
  \centering
  \vspace*{2in}
  {\KJV\Huge\brickred{The Four Gospels}\par}
  \vspace{1in}
  {\KJV\Large\brickred{Translated and Edited}\par}
  \vspace{0.5in}
  {\KJV\Large\brickred{Your Name}\par}
  \vfill
  {\KJV\large\brickred{2023}\par}
}

\begin{document}

% Title Page
\begin{titlepage}
  \titlepagedecor
\end{titlepage}

% Preface/Introduction
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1-2]

% Introduction to Gospel of Matthew
\chapter*{Introduction to the Gospel of Matthew}
\lipsum[3-4]

% Force a page break before the Gospel of Matthew
\clearpage

% Gospel of Matthew
\chapter*{The Gospell of S. Mathewe}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\brickred{T}hys \topmarginnote{Sunday before Nativity of Christ. Holy Fathers.}\readingnote{.i.}ys \readingnote[-40pt]{Mon}the booke of the generacyon of Iesus Chryst, the sonne of Dauid, the sonne of Abraham. Abraham begat Isaac. Isaac begat Iacob. Iacob begat Iudas and hys brethren. Iudas begat Phares and Zaram of Thamar. Phares begat Esrom. Esrom begat Aram. Aram begat Aminadab. Aminadab begat Naasson. Naasson begat Salmon. Salmon begat Boos of Rahab. Boos begat Obed of Ruth. Obed begat Iesse. Iesse begat Dauid the kynge. Dauid the kynge begat Salomon, of her that was the wyfe of Urye. Salomon begat Roboam. Roboam begat Abia. Abia begat Asa. Asa begat Iosaphat. Iosaphat begat Ioram. Ioram begat Osias. Osias begat Ioatham. Ioatham begat Achas. Achas begat Ezechias. Ezechias begat Manasses. Manasses begat Amon. Amon begat Iosias. Iosias begat Ieconias and hys brethren about the tyme they were caryed awaye to Babylon. And after they were brought to Babylon, Iechonias begat Salathiel. Salathiel begat Zorobabel. Zorobabel begat Abiud. Abiud begat Eliachim. Eliachim begat Azor. Azor begat Sadoc. Sadoc begat Achin. Achin begat Eliud. Eliud begat Eleasar. Eleasar begat Matthan: Matthan begat Iacob. Iacob begat Ioseph the husbande of Mary, of whom was borne Iesus, euen he that is called Chryst. And so all the generacyons from Abraham to Dauid, are fourtene generacyons. And from Dauid vnto the captyuyte of Babylon, are fourtene generacyons. And from the captiuyte of Babylon vnto Christ, are fourtene generacyons. \brickred{T}he byrth of Iesus Chryst was on this wyse. \topmarginnote{test note}When his mother Mary was maryed to Ioseph (before they came to dwell togeather) she was founde with chylde by the holy ghoost. 

\end{document}



Could you supply a picture if how this should look like? Maybe hand-drawn.

I uploaded an image of an example of the style I am trying to recreate, with red liturgical notes in the header and footer areas, which chamge on each page.

@Barrett.noah Off topic: what is that language?

Church Slavonic, 16th century, which I am trying to recreate with a 16th century English font/translation.

What if there is more than one top/bottom marginnote? Should they be concatenated, or on separate lines?

Separate lines.

I think the bottom margins could be done best with footnotes. Just format the footnotes without a number, and with the normal font. This also makes sure that enough space is reserved when there is more than one. Unfortunately, for the top margins there is no such mechanism in TeX. If there are several top margin notes, the text body should be shifted down, I think. Is that correct? However that requires special code for the output routine (page builder). If you want to put it in the normal header it may bump into the text.

@PietervanOostrum Great idea with simple formatting of footnotes. Simplifies my need  nicely. It is historically viable to let the top note continue in the bottom, but it is not quite as nice for the reader. In the few instances this happens, I can always do this, and add a second line to the footnote, so not being able to add a second line to the header note is not a game changer. Achieving a one-line header note would be sufficient.

@PietervanOostrum Also, \newcommand{\topmarginnote}[1]{%  \ohead{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\brickred{#1}}} } produces the proper placement and formatting, but treats it as a header, so adding a note on a subsequent page will overwrite the original note. That was as close as I got to a solution.
